# how/where to install plugins which installer is '$ npm install blabla'?

Tags: javascript, php, performance, github, installation

I want to use a plugins and the installation guide is just something like:

'$ npm install blabla'

Where do i have to run this command? how i install things like that (it's full on github)

Answer (score 0):

This is the package manager for Node.js. You need to install node, or more precisely, you need to know if it really is what you are looking for.

Comment: ye ye it is, but i asked if generally, these kind of codes, where have to be run?

Comment: Hum. A command starting with `$` usually refers to a shell-environment command, in the UNIX-like system. This applies to terminal on GNU/Linux, FreeBSD and even Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

NPM stands for Node Package Manager for Node.js. `$npm` is the console command used to download packages from the NPM. You can install it by following the directions [here](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814).

The first gist there will make `npm` a global command in your console. Please provide further specifics on your OS, what module you're trying to install, and for what purpose if you would like more information.

(EXAMPLE)
To install the Grunt Command Line Interface (CLI), you would put the following into your console:

```
$ npm install -g grunt-cli
```

And then follow the directions at [the grunt main site](http://www.gruntjs.com) to implement the CLI in your repository/project.